# Show that a $k$-form $\omega$ is smooth if only if it is smooth as map $\omega : M\rightarrow \Lambda ^k(M)$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Consider $\Lambda ^k(M)=\bigcup_{p\in M}\Lambda ^k(T_{p}M)$ with the natural smooth structure. With this structure I showed that the $\pi :\Lambda ^k(M)\rightarrow M$ projection is smooth.

Show that a $k$-form $\omega$ is smooth if only if it is smooth as map $\omega : M\rightarrow \Lambda ^k(M)$.

Comment: @Mancala: Your bounty suggests that you're unhappy with the current answer. In order for someone to address your concerns, you need to exactly tell us where your problem is.

Answer (score 4):

$\Lambda^kM$ is a smooth manifold in its own right and hence you can ask
for a map $f\colon M \rightarrow \Lambda^kM$ to be smooth. Further such a map is called section of $\pi$, if $\pi (f(x))=x$ for all $x\in M$.

Now a $k$-form $\omega$ can be seen as the map $$M\rightarrow \Lambda^kM, \quad x\mapsto \omega_x \in \Lambda_x^kM,$$
This map is obviuosly a section and your task is to prove that this section (read: "this map, which happens to be a section") is smooth if and only if $\omega$ is a smooth differential form. (What you actually have to do depends on how you have defined what a smooth differential form is. One common definition is that $\omega(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ is smooth for every collection $X_1,\dots,X_k$ of smooth vector fields)

---

**EDIT**:
Assume $M$ has dimension $n$, then $(d \phi_p^*)^{-1}\colon \Lambda_p^kM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \choose k}$. A chart of $\Lambda^kM$ rather looks like $(\phi,(d \phi^*)^{-1})\colon U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n \choose k}$. Let $$F:= (\phi,(d \phi^*)^{-1}) \circ \omega \circ \phi^{-1}\colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n \choose k},$$
then $F(x)=(x,(d \phi_p^*)^{-1}[\omega_p])$, where $\phi(p)=x$. Further
$$
(d\phi_p^*)^{-1}=d(\phi^{-1})_x^*,
$$
so in order for $F$ to be smooth you need that
$$ \mathbb{R}^n \ni 
x \mapsto d(\phi^{-1})_x^*\omega_{\phi^{-1}(x)}=\sum_K a_K(x) dx^K \in \mathbb{R}^{n\choose k}
$$
is smooth. ($K$ runs through ordered multi indices and if $K=(i_1,\dots,i_k)$, then $dx^K=dx_1^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx_1^{i_k}$). For this it is enough that all $a_K$ are smooth. Test this by plugging in vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$.

Comment: I am not able to use this hypothesis to show that $\omega$ is smooth map. Could you help me prove it?

Comment: How do you prove that a map between manifolds is smooth?

Comment: Consider the natural atlas $\{\Lambda ^k(U), (d\varphi^*)^{-1}\}$ for $\Lambda ^k(M)$, where $(U,\varphi)$ chart for $M$ with $\varphi(p)=q$. So,

$(d\varphi^*)^{-1}\circ\omega\circ\varphi(\varphi(p))=(d\varphi^*)^{-1}\circ\omega_{p}\\
=(d\varphi^*)^{-1}_{q}\omega=\omega(d\varphi^{-1}_{q},...,d\varphi^{-1}_{q})$

But are $d\varphi^{-1}_{q}$ fields smooths on M?

Comment: See my edit for a detailed answer.