# $k$-form $\omega$ is smooth iff it is smooth as a section $\omega \colon M\rightarrow \Lambda ^k(M)$ of $\pi$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Consider $\Lambda ^k(M)=\bigcup_{p\in M}\Lambda ^k(T_{p}M)$ with the natural smooth structure, $M$ a smooth manifold. With this structure on $\Lambda ^k(M)$, the $\pi \colon \Lambda ^k(M)\rightarrow M$ projection is smooth.

Show that a $k$-form $\omega$ is smooth iff it is smooth as a section $\omega \colon M\rightarrow \Lambda ^k(M)$ of $\pi$.

I'm trying to use the definition $\omega(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ is smooth for every collection $X_1,\dots,X_k$ of smooth vector fields to show that $\omega$ is smooth as map but I cannot.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797956/help-to-condition-smooth-as-a-section-omega-m-rightarrow-lambda-km-of

Comment: @Watson I had seen this post, but it seems to me that the student could not solve the problem.

Comment: Hint: What is the "natural smooth structure" on $\wedge^k (M)$? What is $\omega$ evaluated on $k$-tuples of basis elements (of $T_p M$)?

Comment: Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722516/prove-the-curvature-tensor-is-a-tensor/2425962#2425962)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the natural atlas $\{\Lambda ^k(U), (d\varphi^*)^{-1}\}$ for $\Lambda ^k(M)$, where $(U,\varphi)$ chart for $M$ with $\varphi(p)=q$. So,

$(d\varphi^*)^{-1}\circ\omega\circ\varphi(\varphi(p))=(d\varphi^*)^{-1}\circ\omega_{p}\\
=(d\varphi^*)^{-1}_{q}\omega=\omega(d\varphi^{-1}_{q},...,d\varphi^{-1}_{q})$

But are $d\varphi^{-1}_{q}$ fields smooths on M?

I'm not sure what I did is right.