# Help for a clearer solution: $k$-form $\omega$ is smooth if only if it is smooth as a map $\omega \colon M\rightarrow \Lambda ^k(M)$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Problem:

> Show that a $k$-form $\omega$ is smooth if only if it is smooth as a map $\omega \colon M\rightarrow \Lambda ^k(M)$.

Help for a clearer solution this problem. I have already seen that this issue was posted in this post: [Help to condition: "smooth as a section $\omega :M\rightarrow \Lambda ^k(M)$ of $\pi$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797956/help-to-condition-smooth-as-a-section-omega-m-rightarrow-lambda-km-of)

but I wanted a somewhat clearer solution. To show that $\omega$ is a smooth k-form I'm trying to use this characterization:

$\omega$ is a $k$-form smooth of $M^n$ if only if $$\omega(X_1,\dots,X_k):M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \text{ give by } \omega(X_1,\dots,X_k)(p)=\omega_p((X_1)_p,\dots,(X_k)_p)(p)$$  is smooth function for every collection $X_1,\dots,X_k$ of smooth vector fields on $M$.

Remark: Consider $\Lambda ^k(M)=\bigcup_{p\in M}\Lambda ^k(T_{p}M)$ with the natural smooth structure, $M$ a smooth $n$-manifold. With this structure on $\Lambda ^k(M)$, the $\pi \colon \Lambda ^k(M)\rightarrow M$ projection is smooth.